# Dropbox API: Query only files/folders from particular path

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

Client.Files.ListFolderAsync("/Path") return both folders and files under the Dropbox selected path. Is there any way I can query ONLY folders or ONLY files?

Answer (score 0):

No, the `ListFolderAsync` method corresponds to the [/files/list_folder endpoint](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder), which doesn't offer a way to return only files or only folders.

We'll consider this a feature request though.